# How do you add an email address for people to contact at the bottom of the hugo site landing page?

Tags: hugo

I thought this would be easy but can't find the info. How do you add a simple email address for people to click so it opens up their email client on a hugo website?  I am trying to make the change in config.toml and have tried this:

```
[[params.links.developer]]
    url = "mailto:foo@bar.com"
    name = "Mail me"
    weight = 4
```

But it opens up in my browser to foo@bar.com which doesn't do anything.

I'd like to add it at bottom of landing page here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a theme, then check how the theme has been built.
If you are building your own site, then you can reference the above in a template with site params:

{{ .Site.Params }} <- this will output all your site params, continue down the tree to whatever you want to display.

If you don't know about params, themese or layouts, then I suggest you start with:
https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/

Which is a great asset.

Answer (score 0):

This is ours:

```
[[params.links.developer]]
  name = "GitHub"
  url = "https://github.com/<our_domain>/"
  icon = "fab fa-github"
  desc = "Development takes place here!"
[[params.links.developer]]
  name = "Slack"
  url = "https://<our_domain>.slack.com"
  icon = "fab fa-slack"
  desc = "Chat with other project developers"
[[params.links.developer]]
  name = "Developer Help"
  url = "mailto:developers-help@<our_domain>.com"
  icon = "fa fa-envelope"
  desc = "Ask questions about the our SDK"
```

So, use no weight at all. Developer places the links on the RH side and User places them to the LH side and they appear in the order you list them. The icons are are FontAwesome icon fonts, btw.

A word of warning: Hugo's config parser blows. It's not robust and is extremely sensitive to directive location. Move any directive at your own risk. If your [[params.link]] section isn't at the bottom of the config.toml, that could be the cause. Ours is at the bottom, appearing just above [modules].

Also, make sure you have: footer_about_disable = false